# Product of Fermionic annihilation and creation operators

Tags: quantum-mechanics, fermions, second-quantization

I have a bunch of fermions with annihilation $c_i$ and creation $c_i^\dagger$ operators. The index $i$ corresponds to different fermions. I'm interested in calculating the product $c_1^{\dagger} \Pi_{i=2}^N c_i c_i^{\dagger}$. Is there some way to re-express this product as a sum? or maybe a simpler way to express the product.

Comment: Do you have any external states?

Comment: @InertialObserver : What do you mean by external states? Each fermion has its Hilbert space of 0 and 1.

Comment: I mean fock states.. Are you calculating an $S$ matrix or something of the form $\langle 0 | \prod c_i c_i^\dagger | 0\rangle$.. ?

Comment: @InertialObserver: No. I don't want to involve Fock states because then the entire operator when expressed within Fock states is simply $|0\cdots\rangle\langle 10\cdots|$. I was wondering if there is some other way to re-express this operator as a summation?

Comment: It's not a normal ordered form. For N=3: $c_1^{\dagger} c_2 c_2^{\dagger} c_3 c_3^{\dagger}$. These terms don't annihilate the vacuum state but rather when acted upon the vacuum state from the right give $c_1^{\dagger}$ acting on the vacuum state.